# Automapper installation from nuget problems

Tags: visual-studio-2015, nuget, automapper

After installing automapper 5.1.1 by Jimmy Bogard from NuGet on my class library project I've got the next issue: no one of other packages such as Entity Framework, Ninject cannot be installed. 
The error message that I've got is:

> "An error occurred while retrieving package metadata for
>   'AutoMapper.5.1.1' from source 'c:\users\username\documents\visual
>   studio 2015\Projects\Solution1\packages'"

Also I cannot uninstall the Automapper package - every time I'm trying it I'm getting about the next:

> "Object reference does not point to an object instance."

I'm using the Visual Studio 2015.

How to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got a solution - I installed update 3 on my VS 2015 and after that the problem has gone. But I still have no idea why I had that problem.

Comment: I'm glad that you have got a solution and share it here. Please mark your answer, which is benefit to other communities who has the same issue. I have checked in all of my Visual Studio 2015 Update 1, Update 2 and Update 3 machine, all of them working fine. So there should something wrong on your NuGet Package Manager installation. After installing Update 3, the installation issue is fixed.

Comment: @Wendy, unfortunately I can't mark my own answer because I had to do it during 2 hours after I answered my question but I didn't it, this is my fault.

Comment: @Nick You can only mark your answer after 24 hours.

Answer (score 12):

Update nuget package manager
Tools>Extensions and Updates>Updates>Visual Studio Gallery> update nuget package manager

Worked for me.

Comment: I too can confirm that updating nuget package manager as explained by Noman resolves the issue. Thanks.